# Decrypting ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor values from another App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have one Rails app which encrypts and decrypts tokens using `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor` and I would like to create a script that would generate a token to be decrypted by the Rails App. Both the Rails App and the script would share the same KEY used in `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor` but I keep getting an error:

```
 Rails -- Exception: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
```

PS: The token is generated and then `Base64.urlsafe_encode64` encoded. What am I missing here?

**EDIT** I'm using the same class in both apps:

```
require "active_support/message_encryptor"
require "base64"

class TokenGenerator
  KEY = "SOME_KEY"
  @payload = {...}

  class << self
    def generate_token
      urlsafe do
        crypt.encrypt_and_sign(@payload)
      end
    end

    private

    def authenticate_token(token)
      crypt.decrypt_and_verify(decode_url(token))
    end

    def decode_url(string)
      Base64.urlsafe_decode64(string)
    end

    def urlsafe
      Base64.urlsafe_encode64(yield, padding: false)
    end

    def crypt
      ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(KEY)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the actual code you're using? The error says there's an `InvalidMessage`. How are you passing the message and the key to the script?

Comment: @JohnP I've edited the question and included the class for reference